# pandas iterate through rows using relative position (YTD calculation example)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have the following dataframe:

[image: Index Returns]

I am trying to iterate through all rows and calculate the YTD performance for each cell based on the month in question. My thought process is to look up the month ID corresponding with the index level and count down that many cells in order to obtain the YTD performance.

For example: Looking at the first value under Column RU30INTR (11720.86) I would look up the month ID and move 11 cells down to the cell corresponding with 12/31/2019. (t/t-11)-1 would give YTD performance. Of course the relative position would change with each row, but should hold given the YTD performance will always correspond the month ID. Month 12 of the prior year would serve as the anchor and then move to the next year once the year is complete.

I've also calculated 1,3,5,7, and 10-year performance using pct_change as that is a fixed relative position. This one is more tricky due to it being a moving target.

I have looked into iterrows(), iteritems(), itertuples, iloc, etc. but seem to have hit a wall with understanding how to iterate through the whole dataframe. I would greatly appreciate any help. Happy to clarify where needed.

Thanks

[image]

df dict below

```
{'Dates': {731: Timestamp('2020-11-30 00:00:00'),
     730: Timestamp('2020-10-30 00:00:00'),
    729: Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00'),
    728: Timestamp('2020-08-31 00:00:00'),
    727: Timestamp('2020-07-31 00:00:00'),
    726: Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00'),
    725: Timestamp('2020-05-29 00:00:00'),
    724: Timestamp('2020-04-30 00:00:00'),
  723: Timestamp('2020-03-31 00:00:00'),
  722: Timestamp('2020-02-28 00:00:00'),
  721: Timestamp('2020-01-31 00:00:00'),
  720: Timestamp('2019-12-31 00:00:00'),
  719: Timestamp('2019-11-29 00:00:00'),
  718: Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00'),
  717: Timestamp('2019-09-30 00:00:00'),
  716: Timestamp('2019-08-30 00:00:00'),
  715: Timestamp('2019-07-31 00:00:00'),
  714: Timestamp('2019-06-28 00:00:00'),
  713: Timestamp('2019-05-31 00:00:00'),
  712: Timestamp('2019-04-30 00:00:00'),
  711: Timestamp('2019-03-29 00:00:00'),
  710: Timestamp('2019-02-28 00:00:00'),
  709: Timestamp('2019-01-31 00:00:00'),
  708: Timestamp('2018-12-31 00:00:00')},
 'Month ID': {731: 11,
  730: 10,
  729: 9,
  728: 8,
  727: 7,
  726: 6,
  725: 5,
  724: 4,
  723: 3,
  722: 2,
  721: 1,
  720: 12,
  719: 11,
  718: 10,
  717: 9,
  716: 8,
  715: 7,
  714: 6,
  713: 5,
  712: 4,
  711: 3,
  710: 2,
  709: 1,
  708: 12},
 'RU30INTR Index': {731: 11720.86,
  730: 10449.63,
  729: 10680.14,
  728: 11083.71,
  727: 10335.0,
  726: 9779.68,
  725: 9561.09,
  724: 9075.74,
  723: 8014.32,
  722: 9292.15,
  721: 10120.78,
  720: 10131.84,
  719: 9847.51,
  718: 9486.89,
  717: 9286.97,
  716: 9126.79,
  715: 9316.72,
  714: 9180.25,
  713: 8577.78,
  712: 9171.27,
  711: 8819.1,
  710: 8692.18,
  709: 8396.87,
  708: 7733.11},
 'RU10INTR Index': {731: 12022.82,
  730: 10756.2,
  729: 11021.99,
  728: 11440.1,
  727: 10657.84,
  726: 10068.29,
  725: 9850.456,
  724: 9356.779,
  723: 8264.663,
  722: 9523.141,
  721: 10370.6,
  720: 10359.42,
  719: 10068.65,
  718: 9701.994,
  717: 9500.642,
  716: 9338.769,
  715: 9513.004,
  714: 9367.528,
  713: 8753.029,
  712: 9348.772,
  711: 8985.885,
  710: 8832.122,
  709: 8542.874,
  708: 7882.31},
 'RU10VATR Index': {731: 1782.662,
  730: 1571.3,
  729: 1592.226,
  728: 1632.322,
  727: 1567.505,
  726: 1507.893,
  725: 1517.969,
  724: 1467.674,
  723: 1319.35,
  722: 1591.293,
  721: 1761.93,
  720: 1800.668,
  719: 1752.459,
  718: 1699.904,
  717: 1676.471,
  716: 1618.719,
  715: 1667.76,
  714: 1654.049,
  713: 1543.267,
  712: 1649.313,
  711: 1592.814,
  710: 1582.751,
  709: 1533.745,
  708: 1422.988},
 'RU10GRTR Index': {731: 2316.922,
  730: 2101.723,
  729: 2175.61,
  728: 2283.027,
  727: 2069.473,
  726: 1921.625,
  725: 1841.44,
  724: 1725.594,
  723: 1503.168,
  722: 1667.177,
  721: 1789.012,
  720: 1749.893,
  719: 1698.643,
  718: 1626.487,
  717: 1581.891,
  716: 1581.695,
  715: 1593.902,
  714: 1558.705,
  713: 1458.538,
  712: 1556.892,
  711: 1489.592,
  710: 1448.367,
  709: 1398.335,
  708: 1283.01}}
```

Comment: can you please post df.to_dict() so we can test our code as well as the expected output

Comment: Hi, I am a little new to this but believe I have posted the dict version of the spreadsheet.

Comment: that is correct now can you please post the expected output so I can test my code

Comment: I am so sorry for the delayed response. I have posted what the expected output would be just above the dict. Included are the original three columns and the last three columns are what the calculation would be for the first 11 months. They are all anchored to the bottom three cells.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that may work for you

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test2.csv')

vCol1 = 'RU30INTR'
vCol2 = 'RU10INTR'
vCol3 = 'RU10VATR'
vCol4 = 'RU10GRTR'
newRows = []
tempRow = None
last_val_is_twelve = False

for row in df.iterrows():
    vals = row[1]

    if tempRow is None:
        tempRow = vals

    elif vals['Month ID'] == 12:
        newRows.append(tempRow)
        last_val_is_twelve = True
        tempRow = vals

    else:
        if last_val_is_twelve:
            last_val_is_twelve = False

        tempRow[vCol1] = tempRow[vCol1] + vals[vCol1]
        tempRow[vCol2] = tempRow[vCol2] + vals[vCol2]
        tempRow[vCol3] = tempRow[vCol3] + vals[vCol3]
        tempRow[vCol4] = tempRow[vCol4] + vals[vCol4]

#append the last tempRow from the iteration to newRows if it hasnt already
if not last_val_is_twelve:
     newRows.append(tempRow)

newData = [[val for val in row[[vCol1, vCol2, vCol3, vCol4]]] for row in newRows]
newDf = pd.DataFrame(newData, columns=[x for x in newRows[0].keys()[3:]])
```